# Future versions of Android and test devices - possible problems

Tags: android, android-2.0-eclair

In the last couple of days, there were some speculations, circulating through the blogosphere, that the future versions of the Android OS, created from the branches Donut and Eclair, won't be compatible with the T-Mobile G1 and Android Dev Phone 1, because of insufficient OS flash storage on those devices.

While that's not confirmed from Google representatives, it's very possible, especially when you look at how Cupcake has pretty much reached the limit of the Dev Phone 1's internal flash storage.

Before HTC releases Donut binaries for the Dev Phone 1, we can't be sure, but this raises some questions like what are the best choices for Android test device and should we be worrying about buying the Dev Phone 1 now.

Another somewhat related question, that I had in mind, is, do you think that Android-based netbooks (eventually without hardware buttons) will be used as test devices and do you plan your development with resolutions bigger than HVGA in mind?

I think that before something like Android Dev Phone 2, the developer community will have to resort to the open market devices and that applications for netbook-class devices will slowly differentiate from the ones that target Android smartphones (maybe different departments in Android market).

What are your thoughts about that?

Comment: P.S.: I added the additional tags you asked for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> While that's not confirmed from Google
>   representatives, it's very possible,
>   especially when you look at how
>   Cupcake has pretty much reached the
>   limit of the Dev Phone 1's internal
>   flash storage.

The media has over-stated the problem, IMHO.

> what are the best choices for Android
>   test device and should we be worrying
>   about buying the Dev Phone 1 now.

AFAIK, ADP1 is out of stock. If you can get a Google Ion device off of eBay, that also is a "dev phone", insofar as it supports flashing alternative firmware.

> do you think that Android-based
>   netbooks (eventually without hardware
>   buttons) will be used as test devices

Any Android device is a test device, for the purposes of testing SDK applications.

> do you plan your development with resolutions bigger than HVGA in mind

I plan my development to at least have a hope of working on screens bigger than HVGA. Without testing on at least a proper larger emulator skin, it is difficult to tell how well those plans work out.

> I think that before something like
>   Android Dev Phone 2, the developer
>   community will have to resort to the
>   open market devices and that
>   applications for netbook-class devices
>   will slowly differentiate from the
>   ones that target Android smartphones
>   (maybe different departments in
>   Android market).

ADP2 will be pointless for 99.99% of Android developers, just as ADP1 is. The advantage those devices offer is the ability to flash your own firmware. If you are not developing your own firmware, the advantage is moot. I *strongly* encourage SDK-level developers to use real consumer ("open market") devices if they can.

Comment: Hello, it seems that I didn't manage to make my point clearer - I know that any Android device can be used as test device (have worked with Dev Phone 1, Hero and prototype netbook) - what I didn't know is what is the adoption percentage of consumer test devices world-wide. If we see successor of the Dev Phone 1, which comes at lower price than its consumer twin, doesn't bind you with subscription program and gives you the ability to easily re-flash its OS to emulate other devices, it wouldn't be pointless, IMHO.
P.S. I loved "The Busy Coder's Guide..", waiting for the Advanced version to ship.

Comment: Ah, sorry, misunderstood the question. I really hope that there is a true consumer flashable device someday that is widely available. I do not think ADP1 sold many compared to the 1+ million regular HTC Dream devices, so in terms of adoption percentage, it's gotta be really low. Google Ion was a limited-release device AFAICT, so it too is small compared to the 1+ million HTC Magics sold. BTW, thanks for the kudos on the book. The Advanced Android book has been in print for about a month, and the digital version is already up to Version 1.1.